# Mysql query SELECT with same name fields

Tags: mysql, select

I have table1 and table2 in a Mysql database.

Each table has a field with the same name, let's say "id".

I need a query where I can get the "id" field value of both tables. I tried this:

```
 SELECT 
   table1.id,
   table2.id
 FROM...
```

But I got an error message:

> Unknown column 'table1.id' in 'field list'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to add `ALIAS` on the columns

```
 SELECT 
   table1.id AS table1_ID,                              -- keyword AS is optional
   table2.id AS table2_ID
 FROM...
```

and call their alias (*for example*) `$row["table1_ID"]` in PHP .

on more thing `Unknown column 'table1.id' in 'field list'` results from columns that are unable to be find by the server on your join statements.

*follow-up question, can you post the whole query?*

Comment: op's error message would indicate that it's mysql complaining about the unknown field, not PHP, most likely due to a bad/missing join

Comment: @MarcB oh! you're exactly right. i was just concerned about the same column names. anyway i will just update the answer.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, I can't get it to work so I did something else instead. I'll try this forward. :D